# ASP.NET page DOCTYPE and Unobtrusive validation

Tags: asp.net, html

I have an ASP.NET web form project set to use unobtrusive validation (via the setting in web.config). Since unobtrusive validation uses HTML5 data-* attributes, is it a must that the page DOCTYPE should be set to HTML5?

The reason I ask is I noticed that this page (created long time ago in VS 2005) has DOCTYPE as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" >
```

Do I need to change it to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

?

Comment: If you want to use HTML5, yes. That's the HTML5 doctype.

Comment: @Tim  Thank you.  But the question I was thinking (probably didn't put it correctly) is that should unobtrusive validation work even if I don't change to the HTML5 doctype?